# Angular No Heroku Não Acessa As URL Digitando

Tags: angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope, angular-routes, angular

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, estou fazendo um soft com Angular 5 e WebService Restful quando eu testo local eu consigo acessar as URL normalmente diretamente quando eu tento fazer isso com a aplicação no Heroku não funciona, só funciona as coisas quando é no botão mesmo, o que pode estar acontecendo?

Minha aplicação: https://escpizzariaview.herokuapp.com/

Comment: resumindo, vc precisa mandar todas as [requisições para o index](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352) (em especial o trecho do "Handle PathLocationStrategy Routing")

Comment: muito obrigado, testei e funcionou perfeitamente.